# Why i can't see shadow generated with this ShadowRenderer?

Tags: java, swing, shadow, swingx

I'm trying to use the [ShadowRenderer](http://download.java.net/javadesktop/swinglabs/releases/weekly/week-44-2006-10-29/swingx/javadoc/org/jdesktop/swingx/graphics/ShadowRenderer.html#createShadow%28java.awt.image.BufferedImage%29) from swingx to create a shadow for a panel. Here is what i did so far:

- Creating the shadow renderer one time in the panel constructor.

  ```
  public CustomPanel() {
      super();
      renderer = new ShadowRenderer(20, 0.5f, Color.RED);
  }
  ```
- Each time the panel is resized, i recalculate the new shadow.

  ```
  @Override
  public void setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
      super.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
      shadow = renderer.createShadow(GraphicsUtilities.createCompatibleTranslucentImage(width, height));
  }
  ```
- And then i override the `paintComponent` method of my panel to draw the generated image:

  ```
  protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g.create();

      g2.drawImage(shadow, 0, 0, null);
      //super.paintComponent(g);
  }
  ```

But the `shadow` image is never shown. Why? I read [this](http://www.curious-creature.org/2007/08/01/rounded-corners-and-shadow-for-dialogs-extreme-gui-makeover/) and i except my code to draw a kind of "shadowed" image generated by the shadow renderer.

Comment: don't you have to paint the image you are shadowing as well? (mind, I'm not overly familiar with that part of SwingX - might help to have a look at the original [example code](http://filthyrichclients.org) - chapter16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a [shortened example of DropShadowDemo](http://www.java.net/download/javadesktop/filthyrichclients/frc-chapter16.zip)

```
JXPanel panel = new JXPanel() {
    int shadowSize = 40;
    ShadowRenderer renderer = new ShadowRenderer(shadowSize/ 2, 0.5f, Color.RED); 
    BufferedImage imageA = 
            XTestUtils.loadDefaultImage("moon.jpg");
    BufferedImage shadow;

    @Override
    public void setBounds(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        super.setBounds(x, y, width, height);
        // not really needed here - the base image size is fixed
        shadow = renderer.createShadow(imageA); 
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        int x = (getWidth() - imageA.getWidth()) / 2;
        int y = (getHeight() - imageA.getHeight()) / 2;

        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        Composite c = g2.getComposite();
        g2.setComposite(AlphaComposite.SrcOver.derive(renderer.getOpacity()));
        g.drawImage(shadow, x - shadowSize / 2, y - shadowSize / 2, null);
        g2.setComposite(c);
        g.drawImage(imageA, x, y, null);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(imageA.getWidth() + shadowSize, imageA.getHeight()+ shadowSize);
    }

};
panel.setOpaque(false);
```

Comment: Possibly the DropShadowBorder class (also from swingx) could also be used.

Comment: @lbalazscs could well be - depends on OP's exact goal :-)

Comment: @lbalazscs yeah but it's kinda ugly and i need shadows for rounded form.

Comment: @kleopatra also could you precise what the XTestUtils.loadDefaultImage method does? Does it create a BufferedImage from a file?

Comment: @nathan exactly, it's just some image - use whatever yours is